# Div with formcontrol validation error message isn't showing after changes in CSS via Flexbox

Tags: html, css, angular, flexbox

I added a div with a button next to the password input fields to show/hide the password text and to position it next to the input field to give the illusion/impression, that it is part of the input field (positioning it in the input field didn't work for me) with flexbox (display: flex, flex-direction: row).

The validation error messages showed up before adding the div and flexbox/css.

I tried putting the input/show-hide-button + the validation error div in one div, with a css class (display: flex, flex-direction: column), but it doesn't work.

Here's the css file:

```
body-container {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 4.8% 35%;
  background-color: var(--white-color);
  margin: 1em 0;


  .content-container {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    border: 1px solid var(--light-border-light);
    border-radius: 16px;
    padding: 2.5em 2em 3em 2em;

    .logo-container {

      .logo {
        display: block;
        width: 28px;
        height: 34px;
        margin: 0 auto 7.08%;
      }

    }

    .login-content-container {
      .input-field-container {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;

        .login-form {


          .login-label {
            font-size: medium;
            width: 100%;
            margin: 1em 0 1.3em 0;
          }

          .username-container {
            margin-bottom: 1.3em;
          }

          .form-group {
          }
        }

        input {
          margin: 0;
          padding: 14px 32px 14px 5px;
          border-color: darkgray;
        }

        .username-container {
        }


        .enter-password-container {
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: column;

          .enterpassword-input {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            align-content: center;

            .password-input-field {
              border-radius: 6px 0px 0px 6px;
            }
          }

          .error-message {

          }

          .visibility-container {
            border-top: 1px solid var(--darkgrey-border-color);
            border-right: 1px solid var(--darkgrey-border-color);
            border-bottom: 1px solid var(--darkgrey-border-color);
            border-radius: 0 6px 6px 0;

            .password-visibility {
              font-size: 11px;
              padding: 0px 0.3em;
              border: 1px transparent;
              background-color: transparent;
              margin: 1.8em 0.2em 1.7em 0.2em;
            }

            .password-visibility:hover {
              curser: pointer;
            }
          }

        }
      }
    }
```

HTML file:

```
<div class="form-group enter-password-container">
            <div class="enterpassword-input">
              <input id="login-login" class="form-control password-input-field"
                     [type]="hideEnteredPassword ? 'password' : 'text'" matInput
                     formControlName="enteredPassword"
                     [ngClass]="{'is-invalid': f['enteredPassword'].errors, 'is-valid': f['enteredPassword'].valid}"
                     placeholder="Password"
                     (click)="onEnterPasswordInput($event)"
                     [(ngModel)]="enteredPassword"
                     (ngModelChange)="onEnteredPasswordChange($event)" required/>
              <div class="visibility-container">
                <button class="password-visibility"
                        (click)="hideEnteredPassword = !hideEnteredPassword">{{hideEnteredPassword ? 'Show' : 'Hide'}}</button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="error-message" *ngIf="submitted && f['enteredPassword'].errors" class="invalid-feedback">
              <div *ngIf="f['enteredPassword'].errors['required']">Password is required</div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: can you please make a stackblitz example or  add gif etc for easy debugging.

Comment: Only enter here to say the **NOT** use [(ngModel)] and formControlName in the same tag